# Selecting rows WHERE LIKE 'ã' (foreign characters) returns all rows?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So my PHP framework code `CacheItem::where('description', 'LIKE', '%ã%')` and my raw SQL query `WHERE description LIKE '%é%'` are returning all rows in  my database - I think its seeing the latin A as a normal a?

How can I select all rows where they have non English characters in the description column? I only want to allow alphanumber (a-z), (0-9), spaces, dots, special characters (!@#$%^&*()<>) and periods, just characters that are English.

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: Laravel PHP framework

Comment: What is the charset of your database table and your MySQL version? I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Utf8mb4 is my charset, the default of Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You could use REGEXP

```
SELECT * FROM <tableName> WHERE description NOT REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]';
```

Comment: Results in [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ CHAR(127)+ '-' +CHAR(255)+']%'' at line 1

Comment: sorry I was in SQL Server land... edited my answer, I believe this should work for mysql